# Abort a GET request in Python when the server is not responding

Tags: python, http, get, long-polling

I've implemented an HTTP long-poller in Python. In simple terms, it's a program which periodically connects to a server and retrieve some informations with a GET request.
The long-polling technique differs from the "normal" polling because if the server receive a request and it doesn't have new data, instead of sending an empty response it waits for new data to become available, leaving the request open.

Basically, when I make a request to this server, it might send me a reply immediately, or it might hold my GET open for minutes.

Everything works fine, the problem shows up when I want my program to close. I've tried both `urllib3` and `requests` modules, they just don't let my program close if there is an hanging request.

So, my question is if there is a way to abort a GET request when the server is not responding (using the mentioned modules).
In these cases, setting a timeout would solve my problem, but it is clearly impossible in this specific situation.

One solution might be to put the request in a thread and kill it when the program closes, but killing a thread isn't a good practice.
Maybe there is a more indicated module to implement long-polling?

Comment: What do you mean `"killing a thread isn't good practice"`?

Comment: Python doesn't let you kill a thread, as far as I know this is usually considered as a bad practice. The only way to achieve this in Python is by using the `multiprocessing` module.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use urllib2 in a thread (I don't see any other way), then close the connection while waiting for response.

The other ways all solve the problem but not in a sense you'd like.

One is that you always return data from the server, but when you have no info to return, return some message indicating that the client should check again later.

One you mentioned is to kill the thread, but, well, it's not really nice solution.

I propose closing the connection to server and waiting for it to break:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from time import sleep

class Req:
    def __init__ (self, url, callback=lambda: None):
        self.polled_conn = None
        self.url   = url
        self.data  = None
        self.error = None
        self.callback = callback
        self.cancelled = 0
        self.polling = 0

    def poll (self):
        thread(self._poll,())

    def get (self):
        self.data  = None
        self.error = None
        cb = self.callback
        self.callback = lambda: None
        thread(self._poll,())
        while self.data==None and self.error==None: sleep(0.001)
        self.callback = cb
        if self.error: raise self.error
        return self.data

    def _poll (self):
        if self.polling: return
        self.polling = 1
        self.data  = None
        self.error = None
        self.cancelled = 0
        try:
            self.polled_conn = u = urlopen(self.url)
        except Exception, e: self.error = e; self.polling = 0; return self.callback()
        try:
            self.data = u.read()
        except AttributeError, e:
            if "recv" in str(e): self.cancelled = 1; self.polling = 0; return # Receiving aborted!
            else: self.error = e
        except IOError, e: self.cancelled = 1; self.polling = 0; return # Receiving aborted
        except Exception, e: self.error = e
        self.polling = 0
        self.callback()

    def cancel (self):
        if self.polled_conn:
            self.polled_conn.close()

    def iscancelled (self): return self.cancelled
```

Some usage is presented through get() method, but you have few more possibilities.
With get() you have standard blocking return of data:

```
r = Req("http://example.com")
data = r.get()
print data
```

To achieve what you want, you can specify a callback here and use it to do something with data, and on program exit you can cancel any pending transfer:

```
def oncallback ():
    if r.data!=None:
        print len(r.data), r.data[:100]
    else: raise r.error
    sleep(1)
    r.poll() # Poll again for new info

r = None
def start ():
    global r
    r = Req("http://example.com", oncallback)
    r.poll()

start()
raw_input() # Wait for enter to close
r.cancel()
print "Cancelling"
if r.polling:
    while not r.iscancelled(): sleep(0.001)
print "Ready to close!"
# You can set r.polling to 1, to prevent the callback to poll again in midle of shutdown
#r.polling = 1 # Dirty trick
# Using threading module would make things just a little easier
```

Or you can still do it without callbacks (asynchronous-like):

```
running = 1
r = Req("http://example.com")
r.poll()
while running:
    if r.error!=None:
        print r.error
        # Decide what to do according to this error
        #if not isinstance(r.error, URLError): r.poll() # or something
        continue
    if r.data==None: sleep(0.001); continue # Do something anyway while waiting for data
    # Data arrived so:
    print data[:100] # Do some stuff
    r.poll() # Poll again for new
    # Somewhere here check whether user wants to close a program and then
    #running = 0 or break

r.cancel()
if r.polling:
    while not r.iscancelled(): sleep(0.001)
```

This works perfectly for me. Either for hanging connection or a transfer in progress.
There may be still some caveats or errors, better to say bugs, to fix.

Comment: I don't believe this! Someone offering an answer that does nothing to solve a problem at all gets up-voted. I offer something that makes sense and got down-voted. People are really strange sometimes. I think a question is clear enough. You need to close a program in middle of HTTP request. Did I get it right? So you have to break the connection. Right?

Comment: I have actually up-voted your answer and down-voted the other, but my votes doesn't change the score yet, I'm sorry.

Comment: Anyway, thanks, your answer is what I was looking for, but it doesn't seems to work. I think I'll put the request on a process and I'll kill it.

Comment: I wrote a  more extensive example. It works for me. Either when a big file is downloading and then I cancel it, or when you wait for data from server. Killing a process or thread in the middle of IO is not really something that should be done.

Comment: Yes, I think this must be the best approach. Thank you for the extensive answer!

Comment: How can ```self.polled_conn``` be set when calling ```cancel()``` if the line that sets it is the blocking ```urlopen()```!? I believe this code works because it leaves urlopen() running in a limbo thread until it times out, if it ever does...

Comment: @Jerther : urlopen() is non-blocking. It returns you a file-like object that understands HTTP protocol. The thing is, we close the socket in the middle of a transfer or maintained connection which produces an error, of course, which we ignore as the desired effect is to interrupt the transfer. The getting of the data is the one that really runs in a thread to allow us to do just that.

Comment: There is the timeout of the urlopen() if the URL cannot be accessed, of course. If your urlopen() blocks, that is what is happening. The urlopen() gets an open port, but the server does not answer on it. The default timeout is pretty long, but you can adjust it either for the underlying socket using the timeout argument of the urlopen() function, or by setting the default timeout for all sockets using the socket module.

Comment: Oh, it's ```u.read()``` that's blocking. Makes sens now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple try-except block with `requests`:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```

Edited to add timeout parameter.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of needing to stop a long running request which isn't returning?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explained well. When I make a request, it hangs, for example, 30 seconds. After these 30 seconds, it returns an empty response. I want to tell requests (or urllib3 or something else) to just give up waiting for the response.

Comment: You can pass `requests` a timeout value like so: `requests.get('http://github.com', timeout=0.001)`. See the documentation here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it will just hang until the 5 seconds is up and then timeout. This answer provides no way to stop the request. The try except block does nothing. See Dalen's answer for an actual solution